# Crear un LINK con 2 o 3 variables input en javascript y html (Blogger)

Tags: javascript, html, input, concatenación, urlencoding

Lo primero muchísimas gracias de antemano por atender mi consulta; Ahí va:

Tengo una página en Blogger y pretendo hacer una promo individualizada que aparezca en cada post automáticamente para que compartan mis posts y monitorizarlo gracias a google analitycs para poder premiarles.

?utm_campaign=**MiPromo**&utm_medium=**VARIABLE1**&utm_source=**VARIABLE2**&utm_term=**VARIABLE3** donde las VARIABLES serían **inputs** que el usuario que visita el post escribiría y después compartirá mediante addtoany.com   `<a href="TodoElEnlaceGenerado">Compartir</a>`

Por lo que el enlace debería ser: [https://www.addtoany.com/share#url=https://NombreDelSitio.blogspot.com/Año/Mes/NombreDelPost.html?utm_campaign=MiPromo&utm_medium=VARIABLE1&utm_source=VARIABLE2&utm_term=VARIABLE3](https://www.addtoany.com/share#url=https://NombreDelSitio.blogspot.com/A%C3%B1o/Mes/NombreDelPost.html?utm_campaign=MiPromo&utm_medium=VARIABLE1&utm_source=VARIABLE2&utm_term=VARIABLE3)

Y... ando muuuuuuy perdido, he revisado códigos y páginas en busca de información pero mis intentos han sido fallidos

Los valores FIJOS son:

- La url de AddToAny
- Las etiquetas UTM_
- El Nombre de la Promo

Los valores VARIABLES son:

- La url del post que con un window.location.href se obtendría
- Las 3 variables a introducir en las etiquetas UTM

Cualquier ayuda y/o guía lo agradeceré.

---

Muchas gracias F.Igor por tomarte el tiempo en contestarme e intentar ayudarme, pero el código que me has aportado no soluciona mi problema, ya que [https://NombreDelSitio.blogspot.com/Año/Mes/NombreDelPost.html](https://NombreDelSitio.blogspot.com/A%C3%B1o/Mes/NombreDelPost.html) es una variable que javascript debe definir.

y ahora en el link solo aparece mi url del post, nada mas ni por delante ni por detrás.

Este es el código que tengo

```
  function generateLink(id,var1,var2,var3){
            
        var lnk=document.getElementById(id);
            console.log(lnk);
        var url="https://www.addtoany.com/share#url=web?utm_campaign=MiPromo&utm_medium=VARIABLE1&utm_source=VARIABLE2&utm_term=VARIABLE3"
        url=url.replace("web"window.location.href);
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE1",var1);
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE2",var2);
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE3",var3);
        lnk.setAttribute("href",url);
  }
  
  generateLink("test1","var1","var2","var3");

</script>
<form>
Nick:<input id="var1" type="text" name="nick" placeholder="TuNickSinEspacios">
Dirección: <input id="var2" type="text" name="canal" placeholder="@Usuario? TuWeB.es">
Donde:<input id="var3" type="text" name="tipo" placeholder="Face,Twitter,Telegram,Web?">
<a href="" id="test1" >Compartir</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un codigo como en este ejemplo. Basicamente estableces el atributo `href` para cada link mediante una funcion con parametros para generar la URL.

```js
function generateLink(id,var1,var2,var3){
        var lnk=document.getElementById(id);
        console.log(lnk);
        var url="https://www.addtoany.com/share#url=https://NombreDelSitio.blogspot.com/Año/Mes/NombreDelPost.html?utm_campaign=MiPromo&utm_medium=VARIABLE1&utm_source=VARIABLE2&utm_term=VARIABLE3"
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE1",var1);
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE2",var2);
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE3",var3);
        lnk.setAttribute("href",url);
  }
  
  generateLink("test1","v1","v2","v3");
  generateLink("test2","x1","x2","x3");
```

```html
<a href="" id="test1" >Test link1</a>
<br>
<a href="" id="test2" >Test link2</a>
```

Aqui`generateLink(id,var1,var2,var3)` se llama por cada link que deseas ajustar usando su `id`.

**EDIT:**

Par el caso de ejemplo mostrado en la pregunta actualizada, debes usar los valores de los input que creaste como parametros. Ademas, usé la funcion `encodeURIComponent()` para asegurar que los valores escritos en la URL sean formateados correctamente:

```html
<form>
Nick:<input id="var1" type="text" onchange="updateLink()" name="nick" placeholder="TuNickSinEspacios">
Dirección: <input id="var2" type="text" onchange="updateLink()" name="canal" placeholder="@Usuario? TuWeB.es">
Donde:<input id="var3" type="text" onchange="updateLink()" name="tipo" placeholder="Face,Twitter,Telegram,Web?">
<a href="" id="test1" target="new" >Compartir</a>
</form>

<script>
function generateLink(id,var1,var2,var3){
            
        var lnk=document.getElementById(id);
        var url="https://www.addtoany.com/share#url=WEB?utm_campaign=MiPromo&utm_medium=VARIABLE1&utm_source=VARIABLE2&utm_term=VARIABLE3"
        url=url.replace("WEB",window.location.href);
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE1",encodeURIComponent(var1));
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE2",encodeURIComponent(var2));
        url=url.replace("VARIABLE3",encodeURIComponent(var3));
        lnk.setAttribute("href",url);
        console.log(lnk);
  }
  
  function updateLink(){
    generateLink("test1",
      document.getElementById("var1").value,
      document.getElementById("var2").value,
      document.getElementById("var3").value
      );
  
  }


</script>
```

Comment: Gracias F.Igor he actualizado la pregunta, ¿podrías echarle un ojo? GRACIAS !!

Comment: He ajsutado un nuevo ejemplo para que genere la url a medida que llena los campos. La url generada se puede abrir (en nueva ventana) o copiar

Comment: Muchísimas gracias F.Igor !!!! ahora si funciona !! además le he añadido que comparta el título de la página con al final del enlace:

..... VARIABLE3&title=TITULO"

url=url.replace("TITULO",window.document.title);